# Favicon not displaying?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

The favicon is not displaying for me; instead, I have the missing file/dead file icon. Am I doing something wrong? I am using Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried loading it directly? http://cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/img/favicon.ico http://cdn.sstatic.net/codegolfmeta/img/favicon.ico

Comment: @gnibbler I can see it there, but not normally (e.g. in the tab).

Comment: If the favicon is reachable (could have been a broken route since it's on a different domain) and still not loading, that seems like a browser bug.

Comment: It sounds like you had a repeated issue fetching it and your browser hard cached a fail.  Hard refreshing (Ctrl+F5) while visiting the icon file, several times, should fix it.  Nothing we can do on our end about that - it's a browser/connection issue.

Comment: @NickCraver Thanks, I can load it up in a different browser. I'll do a hard refresh as you said.

Comment: Okay, it's fixed now. Thanks!